# MYSQL explode search

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field that is build like this "1;2;3;4;8;9;11;"

If I want to search if a number is in this range I do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [id] LIKE '[number];%' OR '%;[number];%'
```

Is there another more easy way where i can split the string?

Many thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: The obvious option would be to normalise the data....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the values in a string, the best way to use `like` is as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE concat(';', @numbers) like concat('%;', [id], ';%')
```

MySQL also offers `find_in_set()` when the delimiter is a comma:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE find_in_set(id, replace(@numers, ';', ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) with a comma delimited string of IDs

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,8,9,11)
```

Comment: Isn't the op asking the other way around?

Comment: i believe the op is asking "the other way around"

Comment: John,  it was a semi-rhetorical question. I'm not sure that's how IN() works.  But without being able to test easily I'll take your word for it :)

Answer (score 0):

1. create another table called `helper` with 2 fields: `number` and `id`. you will need to programmatically create it by splitting the id field and add one row to this table for each number in each id.
2. create an index this table on `number`
3. `select table.* from table where id in (select id from helper where number = 23)`

Comment: assuming of course that you want an efficient lookup rather than a brute force scan

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
SELECT name ,`from`, find_in_set('4' , REPLACE(`from`, ';', ',')) as the_place_of_myval FROM reservation 
having the_place_of_myval != 0
```

- note: that in my query im searching for strings which have number 4

[**demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4629/1)  in my demo there is two examples.